# DAX Cumulative Sum, reset by x period

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a function for a cumulative sum as follows:

```
Actions closed cumulative =
IF(MAX(Dates[Date])<CALCULATE(MIN(Dates[Date]),
        FILTER(all(Dates),Dates[PeriodFiscalYear]=[CurrentPeriod1])),
        CALCULATE(Actions[Actions closed on time],
            FILTER(ALL(Dates),
            Dates[Date]<=max(Dates[Date])
                            )
))
```

Where CurrentPeriod1 is the period we're in, which returns something like this:

```
PeriodFiscalYear | Actions | Actions Closed Cumulative
P01-2018/19      | 4       | 608
P02-2018/19      | 19      | 627
P03-2018/19      |  17     | 644        
P04-2018/19      |  6      | 650
P05-2018/19      |  7      | 657
```

So it's basically counting all the actions closed in the table at the moment but I'd like to reset on a certain number of periods, for example 3 periods would be:

```
PeriodFiscalYear | Actions     | Actions Closed Cumulative    
P12-2017/18      | 10          |
P13-2017/18      | 10          |  
P01-2018/19      | 4           | 24 
P02-2018/19      | 19          | 33 
P03-2018/19      |  17         | 40      
P04-2018/19      |  6          | 42
P05-2018/19      |  7          | 30
```

I'm struggling to understand how to do it, despite quite a lot of reading. I have a calendar table with dates by 13 periods per year and also pretty much every measure you could think of, month, monthyear, monthperiod etc etc. Any help would be appreciated. Ultimate goal is a moving average over a set number of periods.

Thanks

Comment: Does your `Actions` table have dates in it or just periods?

Comment: It's got both but I'm placing each row into a 'period due' column as it's at that the level of granularity I'll be presenting the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `Actions` table uses date values and the periods are stored in the `Dates` table, I suggest first creating an index column for the periods to that they are much easier to work with:

```
PeriodIndex = 100 * VALUE(MID(Dates[PeriodFiscalYear], 5, 4)) +
                    VALUE(MID(Dates[PeriodFiscalYear], 2, 2))
```

These index values should be integers that look like `201804` instead of `P04-2018/19`, for example.

Now that you have the index column to work with, you can write a rolling cumulative sum like this:

```
Trailing3Periods = 
    VAR CurrentPeriod = MAX(Dates[PeriodIndex])
    RETURN CALCULATE(SUM(Actions[Actions closed on time]),
               FILTER(ALL(Dates),
                   Dates[PeriodIndex] <= CurrentPeriod &&
                   Dates[PeriodIndex] > CurrentPeriod - 3))
```

Comment: Thanks for this Alexis. I do have date values and periods in my calendar table and actually got most of the way there, via a similar method. I made a period offset column that returns 0 for current period and -1 for the previous etc. Appreciate your responses.